# Difference between now() and one column with datum (date) in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, difference

I don't have too much experience with the PHP programming language, so I ask you for help solving a small problem.

I have several users in the tabele with their data and one column that lists the date when they need to report to the interview.

I need a sql query syntax to check the following:

Does the database have a user whose date in the table is the same or larger than it currently is. If a user is found, then my program will send an email to remind him.

I will use CRON JOB after to refresh the index.php, thats okay, but bothers me the most that I don't know the date comparison syntax.
Otherwise the date in mysql database for each user is entered in the format 2020-02-15

```
$datenow = date("Y-m-d");
echo $datenow;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'report_date' >= '".$datenow."'";
if ($result = mysqli_query ($con, $sql)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0) {       
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)) {                      
            $id = $row['id'];
            blablablabla
        }
```

Comment: Besides the answer, the regular quotes around the table and column of yours, are incorrect and should be removed.

Comment: Then you have `while($rows...` and using `$row['id']`. That will throw an undefined variable notice.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the question is here.  Aside from the typos mentioned above, the code that you have should work fine.  If you're really just asking for how to do it without the PHP variable, a simple search for something like "mysql current date function" would turn up appropriate results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> bothers me the most that I don't know the date comparison syntax

You seem to be looking for [MySQL date function `current_date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date), which is the equivalent of php function call `date("Y-m-d")`:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE report_date >= current_date;
```

Side note: do not surround the column names with single quotes, otherwise it turns it to a literal string, so you end up comparing *string* `'report_date'` with the date, which will not do what you want. Same goes for the table name, that should not be single quoted either.

Comment: Now all work fine. Thank you people. $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE report_date >= current_date";